# Do I need to release before next alloc?

Tags: ios, objective-c, memory-management

I have a memory management question. I am using a single instance of `AVAudioPlayer` in a singleton pattern to play multiple audio files. I have multiple views which have Play buttons, and when a user comes to a view and presses that button, a global instance of `AVAudioPlayer` gets called, and is instantiated with a new mp3 file:

```
NSURL *audioFileLocationURL = [[NSBundle mainBundle] URLForResource:audioFile withExtension:fileExtension];
NSError *error;
self.audioPlayer = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:audioFileLocationURL error:&error];
```

Now, before I do this for the second time, third, and n-th time, do I need to `release` the previous allocation? Maybe set it to nil?? All I'm trying to do here is to prevent memory leaks.

Before you ask: Yes, I know about `AVQueuePlayer`, and no, I can't use it in this particular case.

Comment: Are you using ARC or MRC?

Comment: Looks like the new projects in Xcode 6 are created with ARC, so ARC

Comment: if ARC is enabled, the previous object is released automatically.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you are assigning to a property (`self.audioPlayer`), you don't need to release in the code you showed.

Ideally, all memory management should be done in the property's accessors. The setter would release the old value and retain (or, for a property with the `copy` attribute, copy) the new value. The getter might just return the value with no memory management, but an atomic property will likely retain and autorelease the value before returning it.

This, of course, assumes that the property was declared `strong`, as it should have been.

Answer (score 0):

If you are not using ARC you should be releasing and setting it to nil.

```
if (self.audioPlayer){
     [_audioPlayer release], _audioPlayer = nil;
}
self.audioPlayer = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:audioFileLocationURL error:&error];
```

Comment: No need to set to `nil` if the next line you assign a new value to it.

Comment: No need for the if check, either, as sending `release` to `nil` is essentially a no-op.

Comment: This is all wrong. The setter for the property takes care of memory management. The caller of the setter should not do so. @rmaddy, it is necessary to set the instance variable to `nil` if you manually release it, because otherwise the property setter would release it again (and it might have been deallocated).